# Parameter in routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have the following route

`Route::get('compare/{user_id}/{compare_id}', 'CompareController@index');`

Since only the owner or members of the working group should have access to this site, I need to filter it. But how can I add the user_id and the compare_id in to the filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you could do this. Firstly you could just use `Request::segment()` to fetch each of the required segments of the URI.

A second and better solution is to get the current route with `Route::getCurrentRoute()`.

```php
Route::filter('example', function()
{
    $route = Route::getCurrentRoute();

    $user_id = $route->getParameter('user_id');
    $compare_id = $route->getParameter('compare_id');
});
```